# I want to print a user specified number of labels without opening Libreoffice

Tags: bash, printing, launcher

I'm using Ubuntu in a restaurant. In this case I'm using a Brother label printer to print "Use By" date labels.

To print one I can use the command `libreoffice -p ~/Desktop/TestLabel.odt`
I have this in a bash script executed from the Launcher.

For certain items it would be convenient to print multiple labels at once rather than clicking the launcher multiple times.

Is there a way to prompt the user for a quantity and print that many times?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple with `zenity`. Expand the script with a command like this:

```
NUMBER=$(zenity --entry --text="How many Labels should be printed?" --entry-text=1)
```

[image]

The variable $NUMBER now contains the input from the user. If the user just presses "OK" it will contain "1".

Unfortunetly `libreoffice` doesn't accept a flag to specify the number of copies. So you have to run the libreoffice command multiple time when printing multiple copies. But, you can instead use libreoffice to preprare the file and then use `lpr` to do the actual print:

```
libreoffice --print-to-file --printer-name printername --outdir /tmp/ file.doc
lpr /tmp/file.ps -${NUMBER} -P printername
rm /tmp/file.ps
```

`lpr` accepts a number of copies flag `-#`.

**EDIT:**

If `lpr` is not working for you just call libreoffice multiple times:

```
for (( c=1; c<=${NUMBER}; c++ )); do
  libreoffice -p file.doc
done
```

Comment: OK I've ended up with the following....
'#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=$(zenity --entry --text="How many Labels should be printed?" --entry-text=1)
libreoffice --invisible --print-to-file --printer-name printername --outdir /tmp/ ~/Desktop/TestLabel.odt
lpr /tmp/TestLabel.ps -# ${NUMBER} -P QL-570
rm /tmp/TestLabel.ps
'
I had to add the "#" to the lpr command to make it work.

So now if I enter "1" i get one copy but if i do "2" I get 4 copies! What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you have to remove the `--printer-name printername` part in the libreoffice command. Can you try that?

Comment: Removed it and still got 4.
Even just lpr /tmp/TestLabel.ps -#2 -P QL-570 gives me 4. Weird.

Comment: Actually even printing the file with 2 copies from a normal printing dialog box gives me 4. Maybe a driver issue.

Comment: Sry, I don't know that issue... But to work around that you can call the `libreoffice -p file.doc` command just multiple times.

Comment: Any hints as to how I might do that? I'm close but no cigar!